# Can't build react-native app with xcode scheme and configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native

Currently i'm developing a react-native application for iOS which uses firebase as the backend.
To separate the 3 environments dev, staging, and prod i created 3 different schemas in xCode with 3 different run configurations.

```
appNameDev => uses the debug run configuration
appNameStaging => uses the staging run configuration
appNameProd => uses the release run configuration
```

In the build phase i use this configuration to pick the right GoogleService-Info.plist

```
case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

   "Debug" )
        echo "BUILD CONFIG: DEBUG"
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/Debug/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;
        
   "Staging" )
    echo "BUILD CONFIG: STAGING"
    cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/Staging/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

   "Release" )
        echo "BUILD CONFIG: RELEASE"
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/Release/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

When i run the different builds from xCode everything works as expected

When it try to run the build with different schemas from the command-line with the react-native cli

```
npx react-native run-ios --scheme appName[stage]
```

it always runs the app with the Debug configuration, which is shown by the xcode terminal output

> "xcodebuild -workspace appNameApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug
> -scheme appNameStaging -destination id=simId"

When i tried to add the configuration in the command

```
npx react-native run-ios --scheme appName[stage] --configuration Release
```

the build is successful, but the app is instantly crashing on start with the following error log

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing Library
> not loaded: @rpath/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL Referenced from:
> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7DABD19-235F-439E-95B6-3EA2607F037D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8463C40A-A7D3-4482-9BED-EC8938BB8483/appName.app/appName
> Reason: tried:
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL'
> (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL' (no such
> file),
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL'
> (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL' (no such
> file),
> '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7DABD19-235F-439E-95B6-3EA2607F037D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8463C40A-A7D3-4482-9BED-EC8938BB8483/appName.app/F
> (terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error by adding OpenSSL to Target's Frameworks & Libraries. Follow these steps in Xcode:

1. Navigate to you project
2. Click on Target
3. In "General" tab, scroll down to Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" section.
4. Click on "+" sign.
5. Search for "OpenSSL"
6. Add it
7. Run a new build

[image]

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I added the ssl framework with the default "embed" setting. App wouldn't build. I switched the setting to "Do not embed". The app built and ran, but still did not launch from the correct scheme. I know this because the correct .env file has the flag `MOCK=true` and the console shows it reads from the default .env with this log `process.env.MOCK undefined`.